# ScrollingMovementMethod() promblem

Tags: android, scroll

So, for big texts I use ScrollingMovementMethod(). But there is one promblem, while the text is pressed to scroll the text turns gray. Can that be fixed?

.java

```
public class Knowledge extends Activity {
Button back, newText;
TextView TVHeading, TV;

void newText() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int n = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
    String text = "knw" + n;
    String resourceId = getResources().getString(
            getResources().getIdentifier(text, "string", getPackageName()));
    String[] knowledgeArray = resourceId.split("\n");
    TVHeading.setText(knowledgeArray[0]);
    TV.setText(knowledgeArray[1]);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.knowledge);
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backKnowledge);
    newText = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newText);
    TVHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.knowledgeTVHeading);
    TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.knowledgeTV);
    TV.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    newText();
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    newText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newText();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Here, but that wont help, promblem is in function, I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using  solid colors for your `textView` attributes as follows:

```
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
```

Comment: ah, also, I see you are good at android programming, what development enivroment do you use? Eclipse is quite slow and laggy.

Comment: At the time being I'm not doing Android development, but I used to use Eclipse earlier and then Android SDK for some time.

Comment: which one is better? how do you think?

Comment: I think the right choice is the Android SDK. IMHO there is a better integration of Android *things*.